# How to format crosstab corner in Cognos

Tags: formatting, reporting, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am using crosstab in my report where i wanted to hide crosstab corner (say "Contract count") but when i tried setting box type equals to none, the output overlapping the column fields into the place of crosstab corner. I want rows to be get populate on the place of crosstab corner. Please advice me if anyone has solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a proper way to do that to hide Crosstab Corner, in order to get you need to follow below steps.

Step 1: Unlock the Crosstab Corner
[image: UNLOCK]

Step2: Change Source type to **Text** from Data Item Label[image: Changing the Source Type]

Step 3: Don't Write any text in the Text source 
Then it will be empty

[image: After Making Source type as text]